# Rails application http request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, apache

When I run my Rails application in Apache using Passenger and open two browser log the request with thread id using log4r.
I see both the request uses same thread id. How is it possible? 
If I do sleep in one request until sleep expire another request is blocked. 
Where can I configure use different thread for each request or maxThreadCount? 
Is it the behavior for development environment or in production too? how to overcome with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
config.threadsafe!
```

put it in your **production.rb** or **development.rb**.

I have same problem when calling a local webservice inside a controller action.

[Puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) also has better concurrency, but that threadsafe confgi make webrick multi-thread for me.